# Why did Helen Cho insist that the Regeneration Cradle should be delivered to Stark?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

After Helen Cho regained her self-control, why did she insist that the Regeneration Cradle should be delivered to Stark? Why not just destroy it? Did she know Stark would use the synthetic being for the birth of the Vision?

Comment: Been a while since I watched it but presumably she wants it to go to Stark because he's a genius and has already studied the Stone.

Comment: But Stark already made a mistake of creating Ultron, and she knew it. @TheLethalCarrot

Comment: Sometimes the most knowledgeable on how to fix a mistake is the one who <s>made</s> created it in the first place.

Comment: Well she wasn't going to be in, and she didn't want to have to schlep over to the parcel depot to pick it up.

Comment: Can we give extra points for proper use of the word schlep?

Comment: Maybe something she saw while under the control of the Mind Stone?

Comment: @DoscoJones - Because she's a schmuck

Answer (score 19):

Remember that Ultron is one of Stark's creations and the cradle contains a physical body for Ultron. The problem is that they can't just destroy the cradle because the Mind Stone is in there. [From the transcript](https://everythingtranscript.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers:_Age_of_Ultron)

> Dr. Helen Cho: He's uploading himself into the body.
>
> Steve Rogers: Where?
>
> Dr. Helen Cho: The real power is inside the Cradle. The gem, its power
> is uncontainable. You can't just blow it up. You have to get the
> Cradle to Stark.

Tony has made this mess and it falls to him to fix it. Blowing it up (the easy path) is off the table and (as the subsequent scenes show) the other Avengers want to know how he's going to fix it as well. Nobody foresaw him making Vision before Bruce sees where Tony's train of thought is headed.